# Por que no muestra este código en Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Trasitional//EN"
"http:www.w3.org/TR/xhtm11/DTD/XHTM11-transitional.dtd">

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript" >
    function saludo(nombre, apellido){
        document write("Hola " + nombre + apellido + "</br>");  
    }; 

    saludo("Renzo ", "Sancho");
    saludo("Marcos "," ");
    saludo("Juan ", "Garcia");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **Te falta añadir un punto después de `document`** , recordar que `write` es una función y `document` el `objeto`, para llamar la función es necesario hacer así `document.write("texto a escribir");` con un **.** que los separe más no un espacio.

Comment: tienes un espacio entre `document` y `write`, cuando debería ser `document.write()`

Comment: Es importante aprendas a manejar el depurador del _explorador web_, este te ayudara a **corregir errores** como el que presentas en tu pregunta, visita el siguiente link: [Depurar código JavaScript con el navegador](http://michelletorres.mx/depurar-codigo-javascript-con-el-navegador/)

Answer (score 3):

Nótese el punto que le falta en la función saludo

```html
<script type="text/javascript" >
    function saludo(nombre, apellido){
        document.write("Hola " + nombre + apellido + "</br>");  
    }; 

    saludo("Renzo ", "Sancho");
    saludo("Marcos "," ");
    saludo("Juan ", "Garcia");
</script>
```